# PyTorch down/up sampling for 1d tensors

Tags: pytorch

I am building a model that takes a 1-D tensor as input. These 1-D tensors can be of different lengths (both very long like 1000 elements and short like ~30 elements), so I am wondering, how can I resize arrays before conveying them to the first layer? Something like `torchvision.transforms.Resize` in case of images. Maybe there are some good techniques for this?

Comment: Afaik there's no built-in method. Some options include padding your inputs to a fixed length, treating your data as a `1xN` image and using torchvision methods, or falling back to [third-party repos](https://github.com/aliutkus/torchinterp1d) that provide 1d interpolation.